# Windows 10 does not shutdown

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown

So, this problem is weird. I've looked through Google and Super User and haven't found any mention of my specific problems.

Whenever I try to shutdown my computer, it will show the "Shutting Down" as usual but after awhile; there's just a black screen. But what's weird is that if I click my mouse or press any key on the keyboard - it will take me to the User password screen.

Comment: Review how to do a clean start and see if you can fix your problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows

Comment: @Appleoddity That doesn't help, sorry.

Comment: disable the fast boot of windows 10 (new since windows 8)